# Do I have to close the HttpRequest input stream which my code never accessed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stream, httprequest

I have some legacy code running in ASP.NET which works something like this:

```
void HandleRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try {
       if( some condition ) {
          try {
             doSomething( context.Request.InputStream );
          } finally {
             context.Request.InputStream.Close();
          }
       }
       // moar code follows which doesn't access InputStream
    } finally {
        context.Request.InputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Note that regardless of whether `InputStream` was accessed it is retrieved and closed. I guess this is waste of time and the second `.Close()` is redundant.

Do I have to close the HttpRequest input stream which my code never accessed?

Comment: why do you even have HttpRequest input stream if your code never access it

Comment: @YagneshCangi: That's legacy code. How do I know?

Comment: How do you know? I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't create `InputStream` you should not be responsible for closing it.

Rules such as that one are there to keep us sane - if you *would* be responsible for closing it, what *other* objects would you be responsible for? `HttpContext` has alot of properties to inspect. And what happens to existing code if they add a new property to `HttpContext`?

If they wanted you to feel responsible for closing it, it should be `public Stream CreateInputStream()` instead, and definitely not a property.

Answer (score 2):

No. It will be disposed by HttpRuntime, which call HttpContext.Request.Dispose after the request is finished. Check the source code here. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpRuntime.cs#c0635347fb5a9826
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpRequest.cs#118b5aa7679e37f7

Comment: I don't see where `HttpRequest._inputStream` is being disposed.